# Contour integral of quotient of polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am asked to compute $\displaystyle A = \int_{\partial \mathcal{D}(0,1)} \frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4z^3-8z^2+z-2}dz$.

Let $\displaystyle g(z)= \frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4z^3-8z^2+z-2}$.

I have found $A = 8\pi i$, but when checking on WolframAlpha I get $A=-\pi$. I don't know where my mistake stems from.

**Step 1**: I find the root of the denominator: $\{-\frac{i}{2}, \frac{i}{2},2\}$. I remark that the moduli of $\frac{i}{2}$ and $-\frac{i}{2}$ are inferior to 1, thus two singularities lie in the contour.

**Step 2**: I define a function $f_1$ and a contour $C_1$ centered in $z_1=-\frac{i}{2}$.
$$\forall z \in C_1, f_1(z)=(z-z_1)g(z)$$

So I have,

$$\forall z \in C_1 \backslash \{z_1\}, g(z)=\frac{f_1(z)}{z-z_1}$$

**Step 3**: I apply the Cauchy integral theorem:

$$\int_{C_1}g(z)dz=\int_{C_1}\frac{f_1(z)}{z-z_1}dz=2\pi i f_1(z_1)=4\pi i$$

**Step 4**: I apply the same reasoning and find again $4\pi i$. (Intuitively, by symmetry, it seems that both integrals should be equal. But I may be wrong).

**Step 5**: I sum the two results obtained at steps 4 and 5, and get $8\pi i$.

I double-checked WolframAlpha and still finds $-\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that integral is equal to $2\pi i$. In fact\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=\pm i/2}\left(\frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4z^3-8z^2+z-2}\right)&=\lim_{z\to\pm i/2}\left(z-\left(\pm\frac i2\right)\right)\frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4z^3-8z^2+z-2}\\&=\left.\frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4(z-2)\left(z+\left(\pm\frac i2\right)\right)}\right|_{z=\pm i/2}\\&=\frac12\end{align}and therefore your integral is equal to $2\pi i\left(\frac12+\frac12\right)=2\pi i$.

---

Here's another approach, which doesn't use residues. If you decompose$$\frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4z^3-8z^2+z-2}$$into partial fractions, you will get$$\frac{1/2}{z-i/2}+\frac{1/2}{z+i/2}+\frac1{z-2},$$and so, by Cauchy's integral formula, that your integral is equal to $2\pi i\left(\frac12+\frac12\right)=2\pi i$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I have not yet studied residuals. For now I am asked to compute it using Cauchy integral theorem. Does my reasoning seem correct to you? Maybe I missed a step, or did a wrong calculation.

Comment: I've added another answer, without residues.

Comment: Oh wow! Indeed much faster than my approach! Out of curiosity, how did you come up with such factorization? In the beginning, I tried simplifying the integral but I couldn't get as far as you went...

Comment: The usual way: writing\begin{align}\frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4z^3-8z^2+z-2}&=\frac{2z^2-2z+1/4}{z^3-2z^2+z/4-1/2}\\&=\frac A{z-i/2}+\frac B{z+i/2}+\frac C{z-2}\end{align}and then solving a system in order to get $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to approach it. Consider the integral

$$\int_{\partial D(0,R)}\frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4z^3-8z^2+z-2}dz$$

for $R>2$. The integral takes on the same value everywhere, and is only one residue away from the integral we want. Parametrizing and taking the limit we get that

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\partial D(0,R)}\frac{8z^2-8z+1}{4z^3-8z^2+z-2}dz = \frac{8i}{4}\cdot 2\pi =4\pi i$$

The residue at $2$ is

$$\lim_{z\to 2}\:(z-2)\cdot\frac{8z^2-8z+1}{(4z^2+1)(z-2)} = 1$$

which means the original integral we wanted was $2\pi i$

Comment: I don't know yet residuals. For now, I should only use Cauchy integral theorem. Maybe you could explain it without residuals? Do you mean that in my calculations I should also take into account $2$ as a root and compute a third integral? (It does not make sense to me since 2 is out of the unit circle).

Comment: @RFTexas With only one pole this is exactly Cauchy integral with no modification